# How to print this string vertically

Tags: c, string, loops

I was assigned to make a program which will output the user's message: reversed, vertically and vertical upside down. I did vertical upside down by total accident but now I can't figure out vertical.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    char str[100];
    int i, len;

    printf("Enter a message \n");
    gets(str);
    len =strlen(str);
    printf("The message reversed: \n");
    for(i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The message vertical upside down \n");

    for(i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%c \n", str[i]);
    }


    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

To be able to output message vertically and also corrections if vertical upside down is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ?

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  printf("%c\n", str[i]);
}
```